# why https request is not working in my react-native app?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, networking, mobile-development

In my react native app , http requests are working fine, but when it comes to https request, it is giving error , network request failed . Problem is bit strange here as if I pick and run any example api from the internet, it is working alright even with https. I can't tell ,if problem is with my api or with my system.

i have tried few solutions ,but they didnt work

Comment: Can you show the error you get

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi. Did you solve this issue?I am experiencing more or less the same problem with my react app.

Comment: Hi @Hamza Hamal, Did you manage to solve this issue? If yes, how? I am also experiencing the same issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I checked my domain for the correct SSL certificate on many resources, but they apparently don't check FQDM. Today I tried it on https://www.digicert.com/help/ and was notified for

`not a fully qualified public domain name or public IP address.`

My issue was SSL related. Just wasn't set up correctly with nginx. Had to combine SSL certificates etc.